# Relation of a SDisk vs FileSystem class

Tags: c++, filesystems

Let's say I have a class that is suppose to represent a disk drive and a class that is suppose to represent a File System. What is the best relation between the two. Should FileSystem be a member of SDisk. But that doesn't seem right because a physical disk drive doesn't have a file system. What i'm saying is that my SDisk class provides low level read and write. So it doesn't make sense for a FileSystem to be a member. There is no need for Sdisk to use FileSystem. However, FileSystem is suppose to utilize the read and write functions of SDisk. But it seems unnatural for a FileSystem to 'have a' SDisk. Basically I want the FileSystm class to be able to use SDisk.

It mosty revolves around mounting the FileSystem or SDisk.

should I have

```
FileSystem::mount (SDisk) or
SDisk::mount (FileSystem)
```

I'm think of having

```
SDiskController::mount(SDisk, FileSystem)
```

which will act as a intermediate

What do you guys think?

Comment: I don´t know if this is a school assignment or a "real" program, but for latter, both are wrong. A todays disk can contain multiple file systems, and a single file system can be on multiple disks. (And another 1000 things are important if you want to implement something properly.)

Comment: I know its now 100% complete. I know i'm missing alot. This is only a basic   version. And no, its not suppose to be realistic, at least not fully.

Comment: now = not; I just want to know which one is the preferred way of handling this particular setup. Of course there probably not how exactly one would implement it.